# Radio button does not update when tab selection is changed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, radio-button

I am implementing a custom text editor, which has MenuItems (File, Edit, Tools-Radio button  bound to DisplayForamt). I have radio-buttons outside a TabControl, and I am binding these radio buttons to a segFile(source object) property DisplayFormat(enum). Whenever I add a new tab I add a new segmentFile. I am able to bind the radio button correctly to DisplayFormat property. However when I click between tabs, radio button does not get updated based on teh active tab? Do I need to handle anything else in the TabSelectionChanged event?

Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <TabControl Width="Auto" Name="EditorTabcontrol" AllowDrop="True"></TabControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

CS:

```
void TabSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (EditorTabcontrol.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        TabItem tab = EditorTabcontrol.SelectedItem as TabItem; // Selected Tab

        if (tab.Content != null)
        {
            RichTextBox txt = tab.Content as RichTextBox; // your textbox
        }

        SegmentFile selectedsegFile = segFileList.ElementAt(EditorTabcontrol.SelectedIndex);
        tab.DataContext = selectedsegFile;

        //foreach (SegmentFile segFile in segFileList)
            //  MessageBox.Show("Segment File: " + segFile.Path + "DispFormat: " + segFile.DisplayFormat);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have established any kind of binding between a particular radiobutton and a particular TabItem? Or, if there is no such binding, how should the RadioButtons know, unless you manipulate the RadioButtons in code-behind?

Comment: I dynamically create tabs, so I dont have any binding with the radio buttons and tabItem, how do I do this type of binding, greatly appreciate if you cound elaborate with little bit of code.

Comment: There is not much to it. Look at the MSDN documentation of [FrameworkElement.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598270.aspx) to know how to do binding in code-behind.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't use DataContext (for whatever reason), you might want to use the other overload of the [FrameworkElement.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273.aspx) method (which gives you more flexibility via usage of BindingBase).

Comment: I have got the binding of the radio button to DisplayFormat property, but how do I bind radio button to active TabItem is the question.

Comment: No, you bind one radio-button to one TabItem. Look up the MSDN documentation for *TabItem.IsSelected*, which is most likely what you want to bind to.

Comment: I greatly appreciate if you could throw some code.

Comment: Is there something particular in the MSDN documentation you don't understand? If so, please tell me and i will gladly clarify/explain. As i see it, you do not really have a problem if you just look into the documentation. Why should i copy'n'paste the code samples from the documentation here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52796/discussion-between-user2495173-and-elgonzo)